# Generate a list of nats, like [1..n] generates a list of ints

Tags: isabelle

I am trying to get this to work

`value "∑k←[1..3::nat]. [1::real, 15, 123.3]!k"`

But the list that k is taking numbers from is always "int list" and then I get the error:
Type unification failed: Clash of types "int" and "nat"...

the bigger example I am trying to use this in is

```
lemma
  fixes a::"real list" and n::"nat"
  assumes "n ≥ 2"
  assumes "length a = n"
  assumes "∀ x. x ∈ (set a) ⟶ x > 0"
  assumes "(sum_list a) = 1"
  shows "∑k←[1..n]. ( ((a!k) / (1 - (a!k))) * (∑i←[1..(k-1)]. (a!i)) )⇧2 < (1/3)"
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Note that the index domain for the `!` operator for a list of length `n` is from `0` to `n - 1`, not from `1` to `n` as your code seems to imply.

Comment: Also, your second sum in the lemma statement might be more conveniently written as something like `sum_list (take k a)`. Or maybe `k - 1`.

Comment: Lastly, for proofs it is usually more convenient to use set-based sums, i.e. `∑k∈{1..n}` instead of `∑k←[1..n]`. Can also be written as `∑k=1..n` for convenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `List.upt` aka `[i..<j]`.

One way to find such functions is to guess the type and use `find_consts`:

```
find_consts "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list"
(*
find_consts
  "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list"

found 1 constant(s):
  List.upt :: "nat ⇒ nat ⇒ nat list"
*)
```

Comment: If you're wondering why there's `[i..<j]` only for natural numbers and `[i..j]` for integers: If you want `[i..j]` for natural numbers you can just write `[i..<j+1]` and if you want `[i..<j]` for integers you can just write `[i..j-1]`. So in some sense, it's the natural choice for `nat` and `int`, respectively.